add new variable and new line in many files present in different directories in bash
I have a directory structure like below in bash.
directory_1
   variables_file.txt
   bash_script.bash
directory_2
   variables_file.txt
   bash_script.bash
   sub_directory_1
       variables_file.txt
       bash_script.bash
directory_3
   variables_file.txt
   bash_script.bash
   

contents of variables_file.txt are below.  Line numbers are for illustration only not in file
1) export src_table_name='test_abc_table'
2) export starttime="$(date --utc "+%Y-%m-%d %T")"
3) export tgt_table_name='test_xyz_table'

I want to add a new variable and a new line after the variable to all the variables_file.txt files irrespective of where they are present.
export abc_test_value='test_command'

Expected contents after adding the new variable to the variables_file.txt are below
1) export src_table_name='test_abc_table'
2) export starttime="$(date --utc "+%Y-%m-%d %T")"
3) export tgt_table_name='test_xyz_table'
4) export abc_test_value='test_command'
5) 

I am able to add manually but it is time taking to add in 100 of similar files.
Is there any other way to do this in bash.

Have you tested to ask the infamous chat? This looks very specific to your needs and not that re-usable.

You can certainly do find . -name variables_file.txt to get a list of all of those files, then run them in a loop.

Pipe a find command to a loop that appends to each of the matching files.
find topdir -name variables_file.txt | while read -r filename; do
    cat >>"$filename" <<EOF
export abc_test_value='test_command'

EOF
done


It would probably be more efficient to use -exec from find instead of a shell while loop.  For multiple commands you can do an sh -c.

I don't see how starting a new shell for each file is more efficient. That shell will still have to do cat >>"$filename"

I have never encountered anything as slow in programming as Bash for loops.  Just a plain Bash loop like time for ((Count=0; Count<10000000; Count++)); do :; done takes 25 seconds on my high-end desktop PC!  The same loop in PHP time php -r 'for ($Count=0; $Count<10000000; $Count++) { };' takes 0.057 seconds.  Bash is unfathomably slow at loops, for some unknown reason.  Using -exec from find is usually orders of magnitude faster than an internal Bash loop, even though it is calling another executable every single iteration.  But I haven't tested it for your particular code.

Unless you're updating thousands of files, who cares?

Your loop has 10 million iterations, no one would use bash for something that large. If there are only 1000 files, 25 seconds becomes 0.002 seconds. Then the bottleneck is the file writing, not the shell loop.

It's not about a 1,000,000 iteration loop, that just glorifies how bad Bash loops are.  Bash lags badly even on small loops of 500 to 2000 files.  It is, as I pointed out, faster to use a find loop that calls those hundreds of sub-shells than an internal Bash loop -- because of how poorly coded Bash loops are.  There is no Bash loop that finishes in 0.002 seconds, except possibly an empty loop that doesn't iterate.

@Raven Choosing between bash loops and find -exec is splitting hairs. Bash is the wrong language for doing anything many thousands of times.
